# Are triangulations of compact manifolds finite?

Tags: geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a compact manifold. Is any triangulation of $X$ by simplices already a finite triangulation? Can you give a proof or counter example?

Comment: I think that this is more of a definition question than a proof/counter-example question.  You can certainly find a covering by infinitely many triangles (with disjoint interiors), the question is whether that is *defined* to be a triangulation.

Comment: A triangulation is a homeomorphism from a simplicial complex to $X$. An infinite simplicial complex is not compact. (It contains an infinite discrete closed set - the centers of all the simplices.)

Comment: @MikeMiller: thanks, this solves the issue.